# Launching ios ipa from terminal command

Tags: ios, command, launching-application

I'm going to use Ranorex to automate my app test.To do so, i will need to launch the RanorexServiceApp on my ios device before i can start my testing script.
How can I launch the RanorexServiceApp from my mac terminal?
ps.:Sorry for bad grammar.

I'hv tried to use airtest, ios-tagent, ideviceinstaller, ios-deploy, libimobiledevice and failed.

Comment: On which platform are you using Ranorex? macOS, Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

First decide what device you want to use:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

This will give you a list of devices:

```
-- iOS 12.0 --
    iPhone 6 Plus (AD61D26E-456A-4B4C-9470-B6C362AC140Q) (Shutdown)
```

Choose the ID (eg. AD61D26E-456A-4B4C-9470-B6C362AC140Q) you want (you can create your own device using `xcrun simctl create` if you want).

Boot the simulator with that device (replacing YOUR-DEVICE-ID with the ID)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator -CurrentDeviceUDID <YOUR-DEVICE-ID>
```

Now you should be able to use simctl to install and launch commands.

```
xcrun simctl install <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <PATH-TO-APPLICATION-BUNDLE>
xcrun simctl launch <YOUR-DEVICE-ID> <BUNDLE-ID-OF-APP-BUNDLE>
```

`xcrun simctl help` for more details.